# cocoa: how to draw points?

Tags: cocoa

I want to draw the track of mouse when it down and move. I think I can do it by get all NSPoints and draw those points, but I don't know how to draw a point on screen. please help me! Or what other method I can do to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not the droids you're looking for.

err ..

I mean: it is not points you want to draw.

Draw lines, from a point to the next. (and then, of course, from the next to the second next and so forth).

Comment: I don't know how to draw it exactly, could you give me some example code? thank you so much